# If something doesn't exist in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently making profile pages for my new website, but the only thing I can't figure out is, how do I check if the user DOESN'T exist in the database, so if the user doesn't exist, I can echo out something saying that `"User not found: lol123"`

Comment: How does the profile page work when a user is found?

Comment: Try to find that user by querying.  If you get 0 rows in the result set, he does not exist.

Comment: Here is some reading material. [MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  Just query the database for a user of that name.  If no records are returned then they don't exist.

Comment: The thing is though, I've already tried this, right now I'm not on my computer, so could you give me the code I would need for this?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but you just run q query the same as you do for a user that does exist (`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = 'lol123'`).  Then check how many records are returned.  If it's zero, the user doesn't exist.

Comment: I've tried this before, it just gives me this error `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`